# How do I remove Real VNC from Kubuntu 16.04 if the packages are not listed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc, kubuntu, realvnc

Real VNC is installed on my system, which is Kubuntu 16.04. I am sure it is there, since the software starts when I start my computer. I wish to remove it, so I tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge realvnc-vnc-server
sudo apt-get purge realvnc-vnc-viewer
```

Doing so yields:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package realvnc-vnc-server
```

And indeed, the packages are not in the list. Does anyone have any clue as to how to remove VNC in my case?

Comment: You can use  `ps` to find what executable runs, and then use `dpkg -S /path/to/file` to list the package that contains it. If there is no package then just remove it.

Comment: This results in 'no path found matching pattern /path/to/file'

Comment: then you can just `rm` it.

Comment: They are in /usr/bin/ . Should I just remove all directories that are vnc? There are more then listed by ps. And if I do this, have I then removed all of vnc or will there be files elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed them. Not sure if everything is gone now, but at least vnc is no longer bugging me :). If you want to add an answer I'll vote for it :)